# CSS: 2 columns depending on landscape mode

Tags: css, ionic-framework, media-queries, landscape

i am working on an ionic app right now.using a list which displays items.then i was asked to make the display change in landscape.what i am trying to implement is:when the phone is  in mode landscape put 2 columns in a row instead of the usual list.after some research i found out about  the media queries and that it can be used for that

```
@media all and (orientation: landscape) {  
column-count:2;
width:50%;
}
```

i am not really sure how to achieve that.
thank you

Comment: So you found the answer, what is the problem?

Comment: put `@media all and (orientation: landscape) { }` in your   stylesheet and any css you want to only apply to landscape, you put inside that: `@media all and (orientation: landscape) {  .columns { column-count: 2; } }` - [here is a how to on media queries](https://www.smashingmagazine.com/2010/07/how-to-use-css3-media-queries-to-create-a-mobile-version-of-your-website/)

Comment: @Pete yes actually that what i was lacking in my code.i 'll give it a try

Comment: You need a CSS selector.

Comment: @broodjetom i don't know what's that to be honest.but i solved it.

Comment: @Pete thaks for the help mate

Comment: Well, stack overflow is here to help you when you can not find something out there on the internet by yourself. But I think you'll be able to find that...